# Close WinForm On Button Click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this syntax on my buton press event, but when I press it - the form does not close.

What is the proper way to close the form on the button press event?

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IxalocToes nip = new IxalocToes();
    nip.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you try `this.Close();`

Comment: `nip` is a *new* object.  Not the one you have on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method `btnClose_Click` runs inside your forms class

`Forms` have a method call `Close`, calling Close() or this.Close() inside the form will close it

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IxalocToes nip = new IxalocToes();
    nip.Close();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: the close(); only works.  The nip.Close(); does not work.  This confuses me?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by many and it is right, calling

```
this.Close() or
Close()
```

will close the form. As you want to know why `nip.Close()` is not working, it's because the button is in a FORM but when you call nip.Close() instead of this.Close(), it will close the new object created, not the one on which the button resides.